# AdSense help to recognize site content and category

Tags: google-adsense

AdSense doesn't approve the request.

The site is articles about pets. Uses a lot of embed(instagram, facebook, twitter) content.

The response from AdSense does not answer the points to improve. So is there any trick or indicator(As `CONTENT UNIQUENESS INDICATOR`) to help me to understand.

Maybe search console or analytics have some data, how google recognize the content.

How to help google to understand that site is about pets?

[Site link](http://petville.co)

If we skip the uniqueness, what would be the next step to check? Maybe the template/design, some info missing?

Email text:

> As has already been stated in the letter with a greeting, after placing the AdSense code on the site, we re-consider your application. As a result of this test, your account has been rejected due to one or more violations.
>   Below are the reasons why your application was rejected.
>   It is not enough content. To make your website in the AdSense program, and display relevant ads its pages should contain enough text so that our professionals can test them and crawler - define their subjects.
>
> We offer the following recommendations for addressing this issue:
>
> Make sure the text on the pages is enough: Web sites containing mostly images, videos and Flash-animated, is not allowed to participate in the program.
>   The text should contain the full sentences and paragraphs, not just headlines.
>   Before submitting an application for participation with AdSense, make sure that the development of the site is fully completed: do not submit an application, if the site is still under development or beta or is a template.
>   Place your ad code on the current page of the site. This page can not be the main website, but if there is nothing other than the AdSense code, your application will be rejected.
>   Create a clear navigation system for users to easily find the desired section or page of the site.
>   If you want to use a YouTube video for commercial purposes, submit the appropriate application. Remember that we do not approve blogs and sites that contain video only.

Comment: We get asked why Google has not approved a site for Adsense periodically, and so far, all the sites have not created any original content often using paid, scraped, spun, shared, or other content. Any site approved for Adsense **must** have unique content. Even if you do have unique content, perhaps it is not clear. Keep in mind that Adsense approval is a manual process. Someone looks at your site. Also keep in mind that the content is evaluated using the search engine itself so that low quality content can easily be discovered.

Comment: @closetnoc all news services HAVE NOT unique content, each represent same event in own way. Basically, 99% of news sites have same data. How do they solve this problem?

Comment: Most news sites do have some unique content that they create. There is a value add component to the sites content. Other than that, I will not get into that argument. I am just telling you why, so far, all sites have been rejected. The take-away is that yo will need unique content. As well, make sure you are not presenting content from other sites that are restricted by copyright or license.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you translated the email from Russian.   Google had translated it from English into Russian.   The original English text can be found here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-guidelines-for-Google-Adsense-to-accept-my-site-request-for-publishing-ads

There appear to be two issues:

1. Your site doesn't have enough pages.   Google requires 50 pages with content to approve an AdSense application.  I only found 5 on your site.
2. Google requires that each page has a paragraph of text with multiple sentences.  Your site has only captions on each image.   They specifically say that only headlines and images is insufficient.   You need paragraphs.

The issue is not that they can't tell what your site is about.  The issue is that you don't have enough pages and that your pages have too many images and not enough paragraphs of text.